# Enable code prettifying for DS SE/fix these tags that have no default

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, status-completed, formatting

It seems like code prettifying is not enabled for this SE. I came across [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25029/custom-loss-function-with-additional-parameter-in-keras) and thought that the lack of syntax highlighting might just be because no default highlighter is defined for [keras](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keras) or [tensorflow](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow) (happened on SO once upon a time). I then went to edit it and tried adding the following highlighting tags to no effect:

```
# At the top of the document
<!-- language-all: python -->
<!-- language-all: py -->  # pretty sure this isn't a valid tag
<!-- language-all: lang-default -->

# At the top of a single code block
<!-- language: python -->
<!-- language: lang-default -->
```

If code prettifying isn't enabled across the SE, could we get it enabled? I realize this isn't an SE specifically for coding questions, but often a little code helps to explain a question succinctly, and having syntax highlighting makes code so much easier to read.

If it's just an issue with these tags, could we add the `lang-default` highlighter to the [keras](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keras) and [tensorflow](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow) tags?

Answer (score 2):

I honestly don't know how to do that, but yes that would be fine. Let me ... see if mod chat can help.